# Timer stops when the screen is locked

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I made a timer, but if I lock the screen, the timer stops ... how can I make it work when I block?

```
-(void)timeRun{
    secondsCount = secondsCount - 1;
    int minuts = secondsCount / 60;
    int seconds = secondsCount - (minuts * 60);
    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minuts, seconds];
    TimerDisplay.text = timerOutput;
    
    
    
    if (secondsCount == 0) {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
        countdownTimer = nil;
        
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID);
    }
    
}
```

> Start the timer here

```
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{
    secondsCount = perVrem;
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    
    
}
```

> Here I set the time 5 minutes

```
-(IBAction)fivemin:(id)sender{perVrem = 300;
    TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"05:00"];}
```

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without more context, but you may need

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

or maybe you need to use

```
dispatch_after
```

or maybe you need to use the wall clock and just use your timer to update some UI.

Yours look like the latter, ie. use the wall clock and your timer just to update. If you count down 5 minutes accurately you'd have a start and end time and use a timer just to update the UI every now and again. So `start` becomes something like

```
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{
    self.start = NSDate.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

and timeRun something like

```
-(void)timeRun{
    secondsCount = (x)( NSDate.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - self.start + 0.5 ); // Add a bit to get rounding right, depends on your types
    ...
```

where `x` will be e.g. `int` or `long` depending on `secondsCount`.